# Are there any operational, combat capable multicopter drones (as of 2019)?

Tags: military, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Are there any small operational military drones with any form of weapons system on board, as of 2019?

I'm basically referring to a more powerful, more sophisticated and refined version of something similar to this:

Comment: If there isn't its only a mater of time

Comment: That kid's dad is going to be really sorry that he didn't supervise his son more closely.

Comment: Interesting links: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.popularmechanics.com/military/aviation/amp26414352/kalashnikov-kub-bla-drone/. https://youtu.be/1zN33m3Dq6Y